# Is there any order behind the chaos of multiplication modulo $p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let's lift the finite group $\mathbb{Z}_p$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ when we're taking magnitudes so the usual ordering we're using.  So we say $a < b$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ iff $a < b$ under inclusion into $\mathbb{Z}$.  That is all unimportant with respect to my question but in case anyone was wondering what ordering we refer to.

So we know that, modulo $p$, $a \lt b$ does not imply $ca \lt cb$, but has anyone studied what actually happens to the direction of $\lt$ under multiplication?

It would be of use to me for googling if I knew what to call a group together with an ordering on the group since google confuses this order with "order of an element".

Comment: What do you mean with the direction of $<$ under multiplication?

Comment: @DanielMontealegre Presumably he means whether you have  $ca < cb$ or $ca > cb$.

Comment: Like, does it switch or stay the same.  Or you could assign a binary value to the two directions.  We know that for $a \lt b$ it never changes to $=$.  The idea is similar to "reverse the direction of an inequality when multiplying by $-1$ in $\mathbb{R}$".

Comment: It sounds like you already know that in a finite field, there is no ordering compatible with the field operations. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156554/can-an-ordered-field-be-finite Here are some terms to help your search: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_group

Comment: A group together with an ordering of its elements is known as an 'ordered group'. Related creatures, such as 'ordered semigroups' are more common though. Also, note that there is no inclusion of $\mathbb Z_p$ into $\mathbb Z$. Your question is not entirely clear.

Comment: The simplest linear congruential pseudorandom number generator is based on $x_{n+1}=cx_n\pmod p$ for cleverly chosen $c$ and $p$. Viewing all residues as being between zero and $p-1$, we find roughly half the time $x_{n+1}\lt x_n$, roughly half the time $x_{n+1}\gt x_n$. So we have $c\gt1$, but $cx_n$ is "random" in relation to $x_n$. If it were any other way, these generators wouldn't be any good.

Comment: Those generators aren't any good.

Comment: Posted (in shorter form) on MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/q/142849/1916

Comment: @Enjoys, they can be good enough, depending on your purpose for them, and your choice of parameters.

Comment: @Zev Chonoles  Is it a bad idea to double post?  I thought this question might be suitable for either site.

Comment: @EnjoysMath: [Crossposting between SE sites is highly frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068) - try one site first, and if you don't get a satisfactory response, ask a moderator to **migrate** the question to a different site. If you insist on posting in many sites, at least provide links to the other posts - as you can imagine, it would be frustrating for someone to put time into answering your question here, only to find out that you'd already gotten an answer elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick and short aswer is that there is no useful ordering in $\Bbb{Z}_p$. A fundamental difficulty is that the "lift" is not unique. Modulo $11$ do you want to lift $10$ as $10$ or $-1$, or $-12\ldots$? Yes, we can make lifting well-defined by insisting
that the lifts are in the interval $[0,p-1]$ or some fixed interval of $p$ integers. Another popular choice is $[-(p-1)/2,(p-1)/2]$. Defining the lifting is not the problem. Lack of an order relation compatible with arithmetic is.

This means that people who are used to solving equations by methods that depend on having the order relation around (such as finding a solution of an equation by dissecting smaller and smaller intervals) need to learn other methods. Lack of ordering means lack of concept of a "small error", so a method based on improving an approximate solution loses its basis.

Yet, ordering the lifts is occasionally useful. [Gauss' Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28number_theory%29) comes to mind. There we are to count how many of the lifts of $a,2a,\ldots,\dfrac{(p-1)}2a$ are larger than $p/2$. That leads eventually to the law of quadratic reciprocity. An essential tool in deciding whether quadratic equations have a solution modulo $p$ or not (among other things).

Lack of an ordering occasionally gives a headache to people working in continuous math side also. Angles between two lines have a similar ambiguity coming from the fact an angle is often defined only up to an integer multiple of $2\pi$. Usually the difficulties there are not severe, because confining ourselves to an interval of length $2\pi$ allows us to isolate any eventual discontinuities, and we can e.g. integrate using polar coordinates quite well. The type of problems that linger are of the type: what's the average of two angles? Is the average of $+1^\circ$ and $-1^\circ$ zero? Why does it change, when we use $359^\circ$ in place of $-1^\circ$? Of course, in a sense, all of the calculus of residues in complex analysis rides on the non-uniqueness of the lift of a compass direction to a real number :-)