# The characteristic of real-closed fields is zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

We know that $F$ is a real-closed field if $F$ is not algebraically closed but $F(\sqrt{-1})$ is algebraically closed.

So I have this question

> What can we say about $\operatorname{char}F$? Is it zero? Why?

Comment: No, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156554/can-an-ordered-field-be-finite

Comment: Is it possible that Char(F) =2?

Comment: Why it has an order?

Comment: Real closed fields by definition are ordered, and hence of characteristic zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition a real-closed field is an ordered field. The required interaction between the arithmetic and the linear order implies  character zero. I do not know whether an infinite field  F with char(F)> 2 and no square root of (-1) can be algebraically completed by adjoining it to F.

Comment: Artin-Schreier implies that a field $F$ whose algebraic closure is $F(\sqrt{-1})$ must be real-closed.