# Show it's impossible to define an operation that satisfies order table.

Tags: field-theory, proof-explanation

> $$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
> + & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
> \hline
> 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
> 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
> 2 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
> \end{array}$$ $$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
> \times &0&1&2\\
> \hline
> 0&0&0&0\\
> 1&0&1&2\\
> 2&0&2&1\\
> \end{array}$$ Using a proof by contradiction, show that it is impossible to define an operation $<$ that
>   satisfies the order axioms.

I'm really stuck here and I don't know how to prove this. The two tables are $3\times3$ addition and multiplication tables.

Comment: First, write down the order axioms. And actually, these are 3×3 tables.

Comment: But how do I use the axioms to prove this. A hint was given: If x /= 0 then x^2 > 0. In particular, 1>0

Comment: Have a look at the duplicate: $0<1<1+1<\ldots<\underbrace{1+\ldots+1}_{p\text{ times}} = 0$. Here $p=3$.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde In fact, you need only the addition table to obtain this contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

We know that an ordered field cannot be finite, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156554/can-an-ordered-field-be-finite). Since we have the finite field $\mathbb{F}_3$ here with addition and multiplication, it cannot be ordered.